# JavaScript - Hide button if user Logged/Not Logged

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to JavaScript and this is what I came up for hiding buttons depending if an user is logged or not. The navbar ids are correct but it does nothing with it.

```
function hideHeaderOptions() {
    let headerUploadPicture = document.getElementById("navbar-upload-picture");
    let headerProfile = document.getElementById("navbar-profile");
    let headerMessages = document.getElementById("navbar-messages");
    let headerResults = document.getElementById("navbar-results");
    let headerLogout = document.getElementById("navbar-logout");
    let headerLogin = document.getElementById("navbar-login");

    if (sessionManager.isLogged()) {
        headerLogin.style.display = "hidden";
    } else {
        headerUploadPicture.style.display = "hidden";
        headerProfile.style.display = "hidden";
        headerMessages.style.display = "hidden";
        headerLogout.style.display = "hidden";
        headerResults.style.display = "hidden";
    }
}
```

Comment: try display = "none";

Comment: See: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)  with +1300 up votes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `none` instead of `hidden` here:

```
     function hideHeaderOptions() {
    
        if (sessionManager.isLogged()) {
            document.getElementById("navbar-login").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("navbar-upload-picture").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("navbar-profile").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("navbar-messages").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("navbar-logout").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("navbar-results").style.display = "none;
       }
}
```

Comment: See: [Do not use the comment sections to encourage or otherwise nudge users towards accepting answers or voting, as the site functionality covers this today.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251288/dealing-with-an-answer-that-wasnt-accepted-maybe-because-a-user-is-a-newbie-on/417578#417578)

Comment: @Yogi Ok Bhai..

Comment: Just to add, it would be a better practice for OP to add and remove the ```hidden``` attribute to the element rather than do an inline style change. That, or create a helper class with just ```display: none``` in it and then apply that class to the elements. The ```hidden``` attribute is what you really want to do though unless there is some other ```display``` property like ```display: flex``` on the element. It is supported by all browsers.